# Getting email address using Google Api PHP Client Library

Tags: google-api-php-client

I am trying to use the Google API PHP Client library for Google Calendar v3.

My website prompts user to do OAuth authentification. And retrieves calendar list, adds/deletes events.
What I don't know is that would that be possible to get google-account(email such as *****@gmail.com) that user uses for OAuth via the PHP library.
I would want this information so that the program can run some code only for specifiec accounts only.

I digged into the code a little, but wasn't successful.

Please somebody help me.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the authenticated users email address is a little tricky.  First off you will have to add another scope probably [email](https://developers.google.com/people/v1/how-tos/authorizing)

```
https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth
```

Then you use the Google+ API to get the person [people.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get)  this should return the email for you.

Comment: Your not responsible for Google changes but responsible for the information you give. Not a big deal just upate the link and will +2 .

Comment: I have 2,651 answers on SO and 132 questions. I hope you dont think that people should go though all their answers and questions to find dead links.  We depend on other users to leave kind **comments** about issues with links.  In the future simply leaving a note to the author would or finding the links and editing it yourself.  If you checked i did update the link after your comment

Comment: You have 2,651 answers but this one was wrong. I downvoted a wrong answer. You got the notification, did the correction. I upvoted. Where is the problem ?